# Inspecting, Modifying, and Triggering an onclick Function on a Live Website

Tags: javascript, web-inspector

On this **live** website, I'm trying to get **previous versions** of Firmware for a camera lens. The companies' support generally ignores you, so I was seeing if I could figure out a workaround lol.

AF 135mm F1.8 FE is on version 5 of the firmware. I'm attempting to get version 4 and version 3.

If I inspect it, the button click triggers the following onclick function:

`<button type="button" class="bt-full black" onclick="FnFileDownload('964','5');">Download</button>`

I've tried modifying the DOM through inspector, swapping out to

`<button type="button" class="bt-full black" onclick="FnFileDownload('964','4');">Download</button>`

But no luck, it still pulls version 5. I was thinking, if I ran something through the console, maybe it would be possible?

https://www.samyanglens.com/en/support/support-download.php?type=3&model=SONY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the server always returns the v5 of the firmware, not a JS related issue. It's the file that's available for downloading.

Comment: I confirmed it by changing the version numbers manually of the download link.

Comment: sad times lol, they must have it built into the function to only return the latest